# Comparing two hashes in perl using ne

Tags: perl, comparison

I am trying to understand a piece of code in perl, but I am having some trouble with it being sort of new to perl programming.

I have two hashes, which are being input the same (key,value) pairs in the same order in different iterations of a for loop.

Iteration 1 creates %hash1, and Iteration 2 creates %hash2.

`%hash1 = (1 => 10,  2 => 20, 3=> 30);`

```
%hash2 = (1 => 10,  2 => 20, 3=> 30);
```

Then a command that compares these: goes as,

```
if (%hash1 ne %hash2) {print "Not Equal"; die;}
```

My question is:

(1) What exactly is compared in the above if statement?

(2) I tried assigning,

```
my $a = %hash1; my $b = %hash2;
```

But these give me outputs like 3/8! 
What could that be?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ne` is the string comparison operator. It's operands are strings, and thus scalars. From [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html),

> If you evaluate a hash in scalar context, it returns false if the hash is empty. If there are any key/value pairs, it returns true; more precisely, the value returned is a string consisting of the number of used buckets and the number of allocated buckets, separated by a slash.

So it's comparing that both hashes have the same number of used buckets and that both hashes have the same number of allocated buckets.

One way to compare the hashes would be to stringify them using [JSON:XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON%3a%3aXS) with `canonical` set.

```
JSON::XS->new->canonical(1)->encode(\%hash)
```

Comment: That was very helpful. Thanks. Just to clarify, am I right in thinking that the number of used buckets is same as the number of keys in the hash?

Comment: Nope. At the heart of a hash table is an array of linked-lists. "Buckets" is the name given to the elements of that array. Each element of the hash is an element of the linked-list, not of the array. There's no relationship between the number of keys and the number of buckets. [Hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Module [Data::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/~dcantrell/Data-Compare-1.22/) available for comparing hashes on CPAN. This works as follows:

```
 use Data::Compare; # exports subroutine: Compare() !
 ...

 my %hash1 = (1 => 10, 2 => 20, 3 => 30);
 my %hash2 = (1 => 10, 2 => 20, 3 => 30);

 # This won't work:
 # if (%hash1 ne %hash2) {print "Not Equal"; die;}

 # This works:
 if( ! Compare(\%hash1, \%hash2)  ) {  print "Not Equal";  die; }

 ...
```

This is not a core module, you'll have to install it. It is also available under activeperl/windows (in their default repository).

Regards,

rbo